# Python: static class variables like in Java?

Tags: java, python, class, oop

In Java, I can give a class a static variable, here it's counter.
I'm incrementing it in the constructor, which gives it the purpose of keeping track of how many objects have been instantiated from this class

```
class Thing
{
    private static int counter;

    public Thing()
    {
        counter++;
    }

    public static int getCounter()
    {
        return counter;
    }

}
```

I could then use counter by using (inside of main, or wherever)

```
int counter = Thing.getCounter()
```

Is there any way of doing this in Python? I know you can essentially have static class variables/attributes by not giving them an underscore prefix, and then accessing them through Class.attribute (rather than Object.attribute or Object.get_attribute), but is there any way to use a static variable within the class itself, just like I did with the Java example where I used a static class variable inside the constructor? It would make sense for there to be a keyword like 'self' for this, although if there is I've not figured it out

Comment: You can access a class variable with `Class.attribute` from inside a method of the class just like you can from outside the class.

Comment: This SO post from the past likely answers your question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Thing:
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self):
        Thing.counter += 1

    @staticmethod
    def getCounter():
        return Thing.counter
```

Example

```
>>> a = Thing()
>>> b = Thing()
>>> Thing.getCounter()
2
```

Comment: Thanks, this all works (I was going to say that you still have to use self in the method arguments, but I tried it without and it works fine, even though it gives me a red underline) I did try this earlier with Thing as the prefix, but I guess it didn't work because I was also changing the self in the method arguments to Thing as well.

Comment: `getCounter` is not an instance method, but a class method, hence you don't need (and want) `self` to be the first argument. Be careful, that contrary to most other OO languages `a` and `b` will have their own `counter` variable, so `a.counter` is different from `Thing.counter`!